How to make a texture glide in the terrain slope direction
I would like to make a water texture glide on the terrain (heightmap), in the direction of the slope of the terrain, to make a flowing water effect.
In the fragment shader used to draw the terrain, I already have high quality normals (bicubic interpolation) that work great for lighting, and the slope is calculated correctly.
This fragment shader code works well to make the texture flow in an arbitrary direction:
vec2 globalTexCoords = FragPos.xz * 0.2; 
float slope = 1-Normal.y;
vec2 flowDirection = vec2(0.0, 1.0);
float flowSpeed = 0.5;
vec2 dudvOffset = globalTexCoords + flowDirection * flowSpeed * time;
dudvOffset = fract(dudvOffset); 
vec3 dudvColor = texture(dudvMap, dudvOffset).rgb;
color = dudvColor;

However, despite my best efforts I don't get how to make the texture flow in the slope direction.
I have tried this:
vec2 flowDirection = normalize(Normal.xz);

But then the terrain is full of weird localized flow artifacts like this:

I have also tried to make the flow speed dependent of the slope:
float flowSpeed = slope * 0.1;

However this doesn't change this bad result and I don't find how to make the water flow in the direction of the slope.
